# Automated Chrome hides text in CodeceptJS WebdriverIO test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io, codeceptjs

I have a fresh install of Chrome Version 67.0.3396.87 and followed the https://codecept.io/quickstart/ to init a project and create the following test:

```
Feature('Hidden Text');

Scenario('test something', (I) => {
    I.amOnPage('/');
    pause();
});
```

The `codecept.json` config is pretty standard:

```
{
  "tests": "./*_test.js",
  "timeout": 10000,
  "output": "./output",
  "helpers": {
    "WebDriverIO": {
      "url": "https://codecept.io",
      "browser": "chrome"
    }
  },
  "include": {
    "I": "./steps_file.js"
  },
  "bootstrap": false,
  "mocha": {},
  "name": "chrome-missing-text"
}
```

When I run the test all text is hidden:

[image]

Interestingly this behaviour also applies to the chrome settings itself (also dev tools), but I can select and copy the "hidden" text and paste it sucessfully:

[image]

I tried to run selenium-standalone via `selenium-standalone start`, this runs selenium-standalone version 3.8.1 and ChromeDriver 2.37.544337 and also with latest selenium-standalone version 3.12.0 and ChromeDriver 2.4.0  downloaded, started manually via `java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar`, it did not changed the result that Chrome hides all text visually.

I am on Mac OS X 10.13.5.

What else can I do to troubleshoot & fix the issue?

I am unsure where to ask this question since I am not sure which part of the stack is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with the mac os terminal in OS X 10.13.5. Starting the selenium server (or the specific test) out of an 3rd party terminal (e.g. using the IntelliJ terminal), the problem does not occur.

Comment: Starting the selenium-server using the WebStorm terminal and then running the test through iTerm works.

Comment: same here, it works fine when starting the tests with VS Code's terminal rather than Terminal.app. I'm on Mac OS 10.12.3

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/183#issuecomment-401820926

You might find a way to pass the `--disable-gpu` flag. That helped me with my own issue:
[Chrome not rendering fonts when opened in terminal or run by webriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51193152/chrome-not-rendering-fonts-when-opened-in-terminal-or-run-by-webriver/)