# Applications not rendering while using selenium webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on functional testing. I'm using selenium, protractor and cucumber with Typescript. I'm generally testing on Chrome.

Recently, I've got a problem with my Chrome webdriver (See the image below).
[Rendering problem on Chromedriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByDAu.png)

As you can see, it seems to be a rendering problem. The problem occurs only when I'm running chrome with selenium webdriver and it triggers with all of my applications.

Environment :

> - MacOS High Sierra
> - Protractor 5.3.2
> - Webdriver-manager 12.0.6
> - ChromeDriver 2.40

Moreover, my colleague who has the same environment and the same projects work perfectly on his machine.

I tried some tricks :

> - uninstall and install Google Chrome
> - downgrade chrome version
> - downgrade chrome driver version
> - Restart my machine and my environment
> - Clean the Chrome webdriver cache
> - Delete and redownload Node modules
> - Pull an ancient version of each project
> - Downgrading and upgrading Protractor

The rendering is working perfectly on Firefox, so the problem is on Chrome only.

By the way, all the page components are in the DOM, it is just about a display problem.

Is anyone got any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried downgrading Protractor version to below or tried upgrading to 5.3.2. I am using the same combination as yours but I have not seen this issue.

Comment: Hello @demouser123, thanks for your suggestion. I tried to upgrade protractor this morning, unfortunately, it changes nothing.

Comment: It seems to be linked to Mac OS Terminal.app. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50833492/automated-chrome-hides-text-in-codeceptjs-webdriverio-test

Comment: Thanks a lot, you made my day !