# Chrome not rendering fonts when opened in terminal or run by webriver

Tags: node.js, macos, google-chrome, fonts, selenium-chromedriver

Google Chrome does not render fonts when run with selenium and chromedriver. Code see below.

**The same issue occurs when opening chrome from the terminal with** `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome`

It looks like this:
[Screenshot of chrome not showing fonts with google start page opened.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kVlv.png)

Setup:

- Google Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99
- macOS sierra, Version 10.12.6
- "chromedriver": "^2.40.0" (package.json)
- "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1"
- node.js v9.11.1

This is my code for running chrome with wedriver:

```
    const {Builder} = require('selenium-webdriver');
    require('chromedriver');
    async function run(){
        let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
        await driver.get('http://www.google.com/');
        await driver.executeAsyncScript(function() {
            let callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
            let fiveSeconds  = 5000
            window.setTimeout(callback, fiveSeconds);
        });
    }
    run();
```

It is the same issue as described here: [Google Chrome shows no text/fonts when opened with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50855640/google-chrome-shows-no-text-fonts-when-opened-with-selenium)

Changing system language to english seems to be a workaround, but that's not an option for me.

This error occured for the first about a month ago.

When querying text elements with selenium, they are recognized and marked as visible.

**Is this a chrome bug or am I doing something wrong?**

Thanks for help.